# JAXB issue in JDK 8

Tags: java, java-8, jaxb

I am trying to unmarshall XML String payload using JAXB in jdk1.8.0_162, while trying to get JAXBContext.newInstance, I am getting javax.xml.bind.JAXBException - with linked exception:[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.xml.jaxb.JaxbContextImpl], any input would be great!

I have tried adding following dependencies in my pom.xml based on different suggestions from various stackoverflow forums, nothing seems to work :

```
<groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency> 
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId> 
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId> 
    <version>1.1.1</version> 
</dependency>

Here is the code snippet : 

String xml = DownloadTDRReport.downloadTDRReport(sdate);
 jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Report.class);
 StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
 Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
 Report report = (Report)u.unmarshal(reader);

Here is the stack trace :

javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.xml.jaxb.JaxbContextImpl]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:226)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:390)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
    at edu.nyu.paygate.batch.RemittanceProcessEBC20.startProcess(RemittanceProcessEBC20.java:350)
    at edu.nyu.paygate.batch.RemittanceProcess.startRemittanceProcess(RemittanceProcess.java:141)
    at edu.nyu.paygate.batch.BatchClient.main(BatchClient.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.xml.jaxb.JaxbContextImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.safeLoadClass(ContextFinder.java:579)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:224)
```

Comment: There is no need to use Jaxb dependency in pom.xml in case of Jdk 8

Comment: Yes, I didn have those dependencies earlier, when I got the error, I started to add these dependencies and try. It's not required in JDK 1.8. I removed them again and tried, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Like Sambit says, you don't need any of these dependencies when you're using JDK 8; JAXB is included with Java already. Is your application running on an app server (GlassFish, JBoss, Tomcat, ...)?

Comment: Yes, I removed all those dependencies which I added after seeing the error. Still the same exception. It's a standalone java application.

Comment: Do you develop with Java 9 or Java 11 too? Make sure you don't have any other JAXB versions on your classpath by accident.

Comment: Any solution to this ?