# Could not find artifact sun-jaxb:jaxb-api:jar:2.2 in central

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jaxb

I am trying to upgrade a project from `JDK 7` to `JDK 8`.
In order to fix some issues during compile time, I needed to upgrade Maven to `3.6.3` as well.
The other issue is fixed with this upgrade however, I am getting the below error during `mvn install`

```
Failed to execute goal on project jbossha-PATCH: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company.wae:jbossha-PATCH:jar:5.1.0.GA: Could not find artifact sun-jaxb:jaxb-api:jar:2.2 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

When I check my m2 repo, the `jax-api.jar` is present under `sun-jaxb` folder. If I delete sun-jaxb, it is created again with jax-api.jar.

This dependency is present in a lot pom.xml within the project.

Why the error is saying that it can not find the artifact and is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: First why do you need to upgrade Maven for an upgrade from JDK 7 to JDK8 ? The files can not being found because they don't exist in Central... also I have my doubts that those files exist in your local cache... please check if they are not named like `..jar.update..` or alike?

Comment: @khmarbaise As soons as upgraded from JDK 7 to 8, during compilation, it got "Failed to execute wsgen", when I investigatd the issue, it was suggested to upgrade jaxws-maven-plugin vers. So, I upgraded to 2.6 but this time, it gave the "plugin requires maven 3.0" error. And I am sure that jaxb-api-2.2.jar exist in my local cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the error is saying that it can not find the artifact and is there a way to solve this issue?

Because the dependency in the POM files is incorrect.  I checked, and there are no official dependencies for "sun-jaxb" in Maven Central.

The correct Maven dependency for the JAXB apis in Java 8 is

```
      <dependency>                                                          
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>                                   
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>                                   
        <version>2.2.8</version>                                            
        <scope>provided</scope>                                             
      </dependency>
```

as described in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63608553".  I checked and the artifact is there, as are older and newer versions.

So a good solution would be to update all of the POM dependencies.

---

Now I presume that you are trying to build was building correctly before you started porting it.  (Did you check?)  If it was, then it must having been getting the "sun-jaxb:jaxb-api:jar:2.2" dependency from ... somewhere:

- It might have been in Maven Central "unofficially" and removed as a result of a clean-up
- You (or the previous maintainer) might have installed it directly into the local repo on your build box.
- You might have been getting it from another repo; e.g. a corporate Maven repo where someone has previously uploaded it.

It would be a good idea to figure out *how* it worked before.

Comment: I marked the answer as accepted. You're right about using sun-jaxb. I updated all dependencies in the project, however I still got the same error. As far as I see from build logs some jars have dependency on `sun-jaxb`. Mainly `jbossha` JAR mentioned in error text. Currently I don't know how to fix the issue. Cause jbossha is not generated due to build fail, and the previous jar before my changes does not have sun-jaxb dependency on pom. Btw, I also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56297220/jaxb-issue-in-jdk-8) that there is no need to use jaxb dependency with Java 8. @Stephen C

Comment: OK, so a JAR such as `jbossha` doesn't have a build dependency.  But if you are building that JAR (using Maven) and getting failures then the POM file for `jbossha` must also have these broken dependencies.  You *could* fix them.  Or you could do what "they" must have done to make the build work; i.e. add the relevant artifacts to your local repo *with the coordinates `sun-jaxb:jaxb-api:jar:2.2`* ... so that your builds can resolve the dependency without fetching it from Maven Central.

Comment: It is also possible that the team who maintain those projects have put the artifacts that you need into *their* public repos.  So you *might* be able to add their repo to your `settings.xml` file as a place to look for artifacts.  These approaches would be easier than modifying lots of POM files in software that you don't (intend to) maintain.

Comment: Thank you very much Stephen. By adding jaxb-api-2.1.4.jar to my local repo the issue is solved. There are some point which still confuses me such as in the original error it was asking for `jaxb-api 2.2` (and before, I tried manually putting ver. 2.2 in my local repo and it was not working), yet I don't what changed but it started asking for ver 2.1.4 and when I added it to my local repo, the issue is fixed. Anyways I will try to figure out what changed. @StephenC